# Attach file to Winform and copy the file to local while running exe c#

Tags: c#, winforms

Is it possible to attach a text file resource to my Winform exe. So when I run the "Form.exe" in another computer then it copy the text file to a specified folder. Please suggest a method to achieve the same. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to add your file as a resource in your project.

[This explains what to do](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3bka19x4(v=vs.100).aspx)

Then select your file and in the properties change the "Build Action" to "Embedded Resource".  This will now embed your file in your output (.exe).

To extract the file you need to do the following;

```
String myProject = "Name of your project";
String file = "Name of your file to extract";
String outputPath = @"c:\path\to\your\output";

using (System.IO.Stream stream = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(myProject + ".Resources." + file))
{
    using (System.IO.FileStream fileStream = new System.IO.FileStream(outputPath + "\\" + file, System.IO.FileMode.Create))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < stream.Length; i++)
        {
            fileStream.WriteByte((byte)stream.ReadByte());
        }
        fileStream.Close();
    }
}
```

Ideally you should check that the file does not already exist before you do this.  Don't forget also to catch exceptions.  Which can be very common when dealing with the file system.

Answer (score 3):

If the resource name is a string:

```
var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
using (var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    string text = reader.ReadToEnd();
    File.WriteAllText(fileName, text);
}
```

else:

```
File.WriteAllText(fileName, Properties.Resources.TextFile1);
```

And also make sure that you have set the Build Action of the resource file to "Embedded Resource".

Answer (score 0):

1. Add the text file to your project resources

   ```
   Properties -> Resources -> Add Resource
   ```
2. Read the data from the resource using

   ```
   var text = Properties.Resources.textFile;
   ```
3. Write to the file with

   ```
   File.WriteAllText(@"C:\test\testOut.txt", text);
   ```